# WPF equivalent of Windows Form Location

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, location

In Windows Forms I could set a form's location by setting the `Location` property to a `Point`. Is it possible to do something similar in WPF?

Currently I know I can set the WPF window's `Left` and `Top` properties to reposition it, but is it possible to set the location by giving it coordinates, like a point?

Comment: What's the difference?  Aren't *Left+Top* and *Coordinates* virtually the same?

Comment: The difference is the number of properties to be altered to set the window's location. Instead of setting left and right, I set left and right in one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always create your own helper method if you would prefer to work with `Point` objects.

```
public Point Location
{
  get
  {
    return new Point(Left, Top);
  }
  set
  {
    Left = value.X;
    Top = value.Y;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You got it right, the only equivalent of the Location property in Winforms is the Left and Top properties in WPF.